# Testing Liferay multiple user login using JMeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, liferay, grinder

I need to test our Liferay application. In researching it sounds like JMeter is the way to go but following this example -> http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

I don't really see a way to pass in more then one account. I have a list of several 1000 accounts, I want each thread to log in using a unique account to simulate the load (Just log in 1000 at a time, wait a minute, log in another 1000, etc, then kill when I hit the max log in that we are testing)

How, using the technologies I have/know (Java) can I pass in an array or other data structure of user logins and get the results I want?

Would there be another way of implementing this besides JMeter. We also have selenium but I don't see how to thread it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following JMeter Test Elements:

1. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - to provide unique username/password combinations
2. [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to group login requests by 1000
3. [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler - to produce delay

You will also need to handle [Liferay Authentication Token](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token) otherwise you won't be able to simulate login, so your test plan should look like:

- Open Login Page - GET Request

  - Extract `p_auth` token value and save it into a JMeter Variable
- Perform Login - POST Request. You should send `p_auth` token value along with credentials

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more details on bypassing CSRF protection in particular and correlation in JMeter in general

Comment: Adding few more words with *Dmitri T*... You can also use `Regular Expression Extractor` to get p_auth for next request from its previous request's response body.